# Contar registros después de obtener resultado de una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

hola tengo la una tabla "time" en la cual se encuentran almacenados registros en formato Datetime, a los cuales he extraido el formato de dia y mes es decir 2016-12-15 17:59:07 seria "sabado" y "diciembre", ahora quiero contar cuantas veces se repiten los dias, es decir cuantas veces se repite el un sabado de diciembre, un lunes de enero, etc. 
El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
select date_format(time, '%W, %M') as dias from Registos where 
course_display_name=  "Manejo_suelo" and video_code ="-y-xeLFee_k" group by 
time;
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
+------------------+
|Monday, January   |
|Monday, January   |
|Monday, Febrary   |
|Monday, March     |
|Tuesday,March     |
|Tuesday, January  |
+------------------+
```

Quiero contar las veces en las que se repite el dia lunes, martes, miercoles, etc, de cada mes.
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

estas buscando hacer una agrupación de los datos, por justamente esa columna..

```
select dias, count(dias)
from tabla
group by dias;
```

Comment: los datos se encuentran en datetime como mencione, al realizar la funcion count el resultado es el siguiente
    +-----------------------+----------+
    |Monday, January   |  1          |
    |Monday, January   |  1          |
    |Monday, Febrary   |  1          |
    |Monday, March     |  1          |
    |Tuesday,March     |  1          |
    |Tuesday, January  |  1          |
    +-----------------------+----------+
lo que quiero es que en ves que salga un 1 por cada dia salga el total de dias repetidos un ejemplo seria que eldia lunes de enero se repito 20 veces

Comment: Sobre la nueva tabla tenias que ejecutar esto... envuelve tu select con esto... ya lo actualizo

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas hacer es una agrupación, como dice la respuesta anterior, pero no deberías hacerlo sobre el *alias* que has asignado a la columna "time" sino mas bien por la misma.

```
SELECT date_format(time, %W, %M) as dias, COUNT(time) 
FROM registros
WHERE course_display_name = "Manejo_suelo" and video_code = "-y-xeLFee_k"
GROUP BY time;
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.